# Rainfall Statistics Wrong Lowest Number C++

Tags: c++

```
Please enter rainfall for month 1:1
Please enter rainfall for month 2:2
Please enter rainfall for month 3:3
Please enter rainfall for month 4:4
Please enter rainfall for month 5:5
Please enter rainfall for month 6:6
Please enter rainfall for month 7:7
Please enter rainfall for month 8:8
Please enter rainfall for month 9:9
Please enter rainfall for month 10:10
Please enter rainfall for month 11:11
Please enter rainfall for month 12:12
Total rainfall was: 78.00
Average rainfall was: 6.50
Highest rainfall was: 12.00
Lowest rainfall was: -92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00
Would you like to repeat the program? (Y/N)N
Press any key to continue ...
```

So my code works properly, as in no error messages, but the lowest number result is way off and can't see why. Any thoughts or help? Thing is I don't see why it isn't happening to other parts of the code except the lowest result.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int month_array = 12;
double rainFall[month_array];
double yearly = 0;
double lowest = 0;
double highest = 0;
double average = 0;
double rainMonth = 0;
char repeat = 'Y';

//Repeat Loop
while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')
{

for (int i = 0; i < month_array; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter rainfall for month " << (i + 1) << ":";
    cin >> rainFall[i];
    yearly += rainFall[i];
    while (rainFall[i] < 0)
    {
        cout << "No negative numbers, Please try again: ";
        cin >> rainFall[i];
    }
}

average = yearly / 12;

highest = rainFall[0];
lowest = rainFall[0];

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    rainMonth = rainFall[i];
    if (rainMonth < lowest)
        lowest = rainMonth;
    if (rainMonth > highest)
        highest = rainMonth;
}

cout << "Total rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << yearly << endl;
cout << "Average rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << average << endl;
cout << "Highest rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << highest << endl;
cout << "Lowest rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << lowest << endl;

cout << "Would you like to repeat the program? (Y/N)";
cin >> repeat;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Side note: move the `yearly += rainFall[i];` line **after** the check for negative value

Answer (score 3):

> my code works properly, as in no error messages

This is called "my code compiles properly", which is a good first step.

The problem is that your code goes past the 12-th month here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
```

It does not work for the largest value either due to undefined behavior, but the location from which you read thirteenth value happens to have a low number.

You could fix this by using `i < 12` instead, but that would hard-code the size of the array. A better approach is to use [`std::array<double,12>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for the numbers, and use its `begin`/`end` iterators to access the individual values, or even call `min_element` to avoid writing your own loop:

```
array<double,12> rainFall;
...
double highest = *min_element(rainFall.begin(), rainFall.end());
double lowest = *min_element(rainFall.begin(), rainFall.end());
```

Comment: Or, at least, use the already defined constant `month_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop should terminate at `i<12` not `i<=12`

```
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
    rainMonth = rainFall[i];
    if (rainMonth < lowest)
        lowest = rainMonth;
    if (rainMonth > highest)
        highest = rainMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int month_array = 12;
double rainFall[month_array];
double yearly = 0;
double lowest;
double highest;
double average;
double rainMonth;
char repeat = 'Y';

//Repeat Loop
while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')
{

for (int i = 0; i < month_array; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter rainfall for month " << (i + 1) << ":";
    cin >> rainFall[i];

    while (rainFall[i] < 0)
    {
        cout << "No negative numbers, Please try again: ";
        cin >> rainFall[i];
    }

    yearly += rainFall[i];
}

average = yearly / 12;

highest = -99999999;
lowest = 99999999;

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    rainMonth = rainFall[i];

    if (rainMonth < lowest)
        lowest = rainMonth;
    if (rainMonth > highest)
        highest = rainMonth;
}

cout << "Total rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << yearly << endl;
cout << "Average rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << average << endl;
cout << "Highest rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << highest << endl;
cout << "Lowest rainfall was: " << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed << lowest << endl;

cout << "Would you like to repeat the program? (Y/N)";
cin >> repeat;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: This is not going to work, because OP sets `lowest = rainFall[0];` later on.

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: It should. OP uses a different algorithm, which does not care about the actual highest/lowest number in the array. For example, your algorithm would produce a wrong number if the lowest value happens to be above `99999999`, or the highest number happens to be smaller than negative `-99999999`. OP's approach is free from this shortcoming.

Comment: Try this, I corrected a bunch of stuff.  It will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have shown you, you're trying to access a 13th element in the array which is not there. Remember that an array starts at element 0 and not 1. This is a common mistake for inexperienced programmers.

Remember you initialized `double rainFall[month_array];` and `const int month_array = 12;`. So if you try to run `for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)` and you use `i` to access each element in the `rainFall` array, you're already starting at element 1 which is the *second element* in the array.

To fix it you have many options, one of which is to change the first line in the **for** loop to: `rainMonth = rainFall[i-1];`

But if you want to be consistent, change the loop condition to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
```

Hope that helps!

---

E.g. `for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)`

That will allow you to access every element after the first in the array you have.

Comment: starting at 1 is correct - he sets min and max to element 0

Comment: Oh yes you're right. I didn't notice what the loop was doing at first.